# Maven uses wrong jdk

Tags: maven, java

I have env.variable $JAVA_HOME it points to folder with jdk7
but if I execute "mvn -version" I see next

```
MacBook-Pro-Erik:~ erik$ mvn -version
728-version
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 06:15:32+0400)
Maven home: /Users/erik/distribs/maven/apache-maven-3.1.0
Java version: 1.6.0_51, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

How to enforce maven to use correct jdk? I have java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError becouse of this issue :(

Comment: i guess if you type `java -version` in command line you will get jvm 1.6 (like above). You can try to add your "correct" jdk bin path to windows PATH equivalent on mac.

Comment: unfortunately no `MacBook-Pro-Erik:~ erik$ java -version java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by:

```
echo JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` | sudo tee -a /etc/mavenrc
```